# Does the normal reaction contribute to acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

For context: A horizontal platform of mass $120kg$ is supported by a vertical steel rod, as shown in the diagram. The platform is being lowered and decelerating from $3.2ms^{-2}$ to rest in 4.5 seconds. Find the thrust in the rod.
I've done the question and got the required answer.

But if the platform exerts its weight on the steel rod, why isn't there a reaction force acting upwards, and so contributing to acceleration? At least that's what my textbook indicates.

[image: diagram]

How about the case where there is someone on ice, and the person pushes against a wall? There, the reaction force leads to acceleration right? Why does the reaction force contribute to acceleration in the second example but not the first?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the normal force *is* contributing to the *net acceleration* of the object.

In the case of the platform, the normal force of the vertical steel rod is countering the force of gravity.  If that normal force were not there, then the supported mass would be accelerating downwards instead.

If the steel rod were to push with a force greater than the force of gravity on the platform, then the platform would start accelerating upwards due to that net force.

This is essentially what happens when an ice skater pushes against a wall.  They are pushing against the wall with a greater force than the friction between their feet and the ground is able to resist.  The harder they push, the greater the reaction force, and therefore the more net force they will have away from the wall.

Basically, all the reaction forces will cause an acceleration in isolation; but in many situations of static objects, they have multiple forces acting on them which balance out to no net force, and therefore no net acceleration.  The the case of platforms being held up by rods, if the rod is just a static object, it wont be able to provide a reaction force greater than the force due to the weight above it.  You would need something capable of adding energy to the rods to get them to apply a force that can *overcome* the weight of the platform.

Comment: Okay. I'm still a little confused though - when do I ignore reaction forces then? Always when I'm dealing with static objects?

Comment: @GabN. You don't ignore the reaction forces at all.  If you ignored the reaction force here, the platform would have the force of it's weight acting downwards with nothing else acting against it, therefore it would accelerate at $9.81 \frac{m}{s^2}$ towards the ground.

Comment: But when working out the answer, I didn't acknowledge R, and the answer was still correct. I said resultant force = 120g - T, set that equal to 120a and found the thrust. But wouldn't the answer be different if the resultant force was 120g-R-T?

Comment: @GabN. Assuming I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, the T (I assume thrust?) comes from the reaction force.  The T is coming from the rod.  When the system is stationary T = W (where W is the weight of the platform, so 120 kg * g).

Comment: I think I'm getting this slightly more. I do think there is something fundamental I'm missing though - if T (thrust) is part of the reaction force, and when the system is stationary T=W, then what happens to the rest of the reaction force? Is there none?